# Finding the truth value

Tags: calculus, logic

How to find the truth value of:
$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[1 + \frac{\ln\left(10\right)}{n}\right]^{n} = 10$ is necessary for

$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\left[1 +  \frac{\ln\left(10\right)}{n}\right]^{n} = 1$

I don't know how to compute the imit. Any help please

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  If the limit is 10, then it can't be 1.  Anyway, the limit you're looking at is related to the exponential function.

Comment: This is for  finding the truth value for p implies q,which is equivalent to q is necessary for p. want to know if the above statement is True or False.and how to get the answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is, but I suspect the answer might be, more or less,

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n = e^x.
$$